# Count not blank cells for average calculation (not in range)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formula where I calculate average percentage:

```
=CEILING((G157+G171+G185+G199+G213+G227+G241)/7;0,001)*100&" %"
```

However this will not work as some of cells can be blank then we need to divide by some other number than 7 in order to get correct procentage.

I know I can count blank cells in range `=COUNTBLANK(B4:B9)`, but this will not work in my case.

Is there a better = more simple solution than writing something like this?:

```
=CEILING((G157+G171+G185+G199+G213+G227+G241)/(IF(G157=0;0;1)+IF(G171=0;0;1)+IF(G185=0;0;1)+IF(G199=0;0;1)+IF(G213=0;0;1)+IF(G227=0;0;1)+IF(G241=0;0;1));0,001)*100&" %"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use INDEX:

If one has Office 365 with dynamic array formulas:

```
=TEXT(CEILING(SUM(INDEX(G:G,{157,171,185,199,213,227,241}))/SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(INDEX(G:G,{157,171,185,199,213,227,241}))>0)),0.001),"0.0%")
```

If not:

```
=TEXT(CEILING(SUM(INDEX(G:G,N(IF({1},{157,171,185,199,213,227,241}))))/SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(INDEX(G:G,N(IF({1},{157,171,185,199,213,227,241}))))>0)),0.001),"0.0%")
```

You will probably need to change all the `,` to `;` and the `.` to `,`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In terms of performance, I guess this one is better than mine? `=TEXT(CEILING(SUM(INDEX(G:G,N(IF({1},{2,3,5,7,10,15,20}))))/SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(INDEX(G:G,N(IF({1},{2,3,5,7,10,15,20}))))>0)),0.001),"0.0%")
`

Answer (score 3):

`AVERAGE` will ignore blank cells (and text), so you just need to replace:

```
(G157+G171+G185+G199+G213+G227+G241)/7
```

with:

```
AVERAGE(G157,G171,G185,G199,G213,G227,G241)
```

i.e:

```
=CEILING(AVERAGE(G157,G171,G185,G199,G213,G227,G241),0.001)*100&" %"
```

(replace the commas with semicolon, and my decimal with a comma, as per your settings).